# How to add unit testing in strapi version 4 using jest?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, strapi

I'm trying to add unit testing on a brand new strapi application. The official documentation is still in progress. So, until the documentation is being ready is there a way to add jest unit testing to strapi application ? i followed the approach in the v3 documentation with no luck.

Comment: Too broad. Please explain the specific problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are quite a few changes from Strapi V3 to Strapi V4 when it comes to initializing a Strapi application's APIs. The most important changes are how Strapi populates the KOA routes, and how to make requests to the http server.

To populate the KOA routes use

```
await instance.server.mount();
```

instead of

```
await instance.app
       .use(instance.router.routes()) // populate KOA routes
       .use(instance.router.allowedMethods()); // populate KOA methods
instance.server = http.createServer(instance.app.callback());
```

To call the http server use

```
 strapi.server.httpServer
```

instead of

```
 strapi.server
```

You also need to use the new database configuration schema when defining your test database. You can use the following as an initial setup for your tests.

#### The following is an updated (and WIP) guide based on [Strapi V3 Unit Testing guide](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/guides/unit-testing.html#install-test-tools).

First run

```
 yarn add --dev jest supertest sqlite3
```

or

```
 npm install --save-dev jest supertest sqlite3
```

Then add the following to your **./package.json** scripts:

```
"scripts": {
   // ...strapi scripts
  "test": "jest --forceExit --detectOpenHandles", //add
  "watch": "yarn test --watch", // optional
}
```

Then add the following files:

**./jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    verbose: true,
    testPathIgnorePatterns: [
        "/node_modules/",
        ".tmp",
        ".cache"
    ],
    modulePaths: [
        "/node_modules/",
    ],
    testEnvironment: "node",
};
```

**./config/env/test/database.json**

```
{
    "connection": {
        "client": "sqlite",
        "connection": {
            "filename": ".tmp/test.db"
        },
        "useNullAsDefault": true,
        "pool": {
            "min": 0,
            "max": 1
        }
    }
}
```

**./tests/helpers/strapi.js**

```
const Strapi = require("@strapi/strapi");
const fs = require("fs");

let instance;

async function setupStrapi() {
  if (!instance) {
    await Strapi().load();
    instance = strapi;
    await instance.server.mount();
  }
  return instance;
}

async function cleanupStrapi() {
  const dbSettings = strapi.config.get("database.connection");
  const tmpDbFile = dbSettings.connection.filename

  //close server to release the db-file
  await strapi.server.httpServer.close();

  //delete test database after all tests
  if (dbSettings && tmpDbFile) {
    if (fs.existsSync(tmpDbFile)) {
      fs.unlinkSync(tmpDbFile);
    }
  }
  // close the connection to the database
  await strapi.db.connection.destroy();
}

module.exports = { setupStrapi, cleanupStrapi };
```

Note that you need to have the /hello endpoint in your project as specified [in the strapi docs](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/controllers.html) for the next tests to pass.

**./tests/app.test.js**

```
const { setupStrapi, cleanupStrapi } = require("./helpers/strapi");

jest.setTimeout(15000);

beforeAll(async () => {
  await setupStrapi(); 
});

afterAll(async () => {
 await cleanupStrapi();
});

it("strapi is defined", () => {
  expect(strapi).toBeDefined();
});

require('./hello')
```

**./tests/hello/index.js**

```
const request = require('supertest');

it('should return hello world', async () => {
  await request(strapi.server.httpServer) 
    .get('/api/hello')
    .expect(200) // Expect response http code 200
});
```

I hope this helps anyone struggling with the same issues. I will update the answer as I progress.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).